# TypeError: 'FieldValue object has no attribute'_getitem_'

Tags: python-2.7, abaqus

This is a code to find out maximum displacement using Python script modeled in Abaqus:

```
from odbAccess import *
import os
os.chdir(r"dir")
odb = openOdb('Job.odb')
step = odb.steps['Blast Load']
frame = step.frames[-1]
max_U3 = 0
disp = frame.fieldOutputs['U']
nodes = odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['NODE']
NodalDisp = disp.getSubset(region=nodes)
for DispVal in NodalDisp.values:
    if DispVal[2]>max_U3:
        max_U3 = DispVal[2]

output = open('Output.txt', 'w')
output.write('%g \n' % (max_U3))
output.close()
```

The error which is showing in line 12 is :
TypeError: 'FieldValue object has no attribute'_ getitem _'

Can anyone help me in solving the issue?

Comment: What type is `DispVal`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `DispVal`is not a list nor a string, it's a FieldValue. Therefore, you can't access `DispVal[2]`.

Check the methods this object offers, you probably have something like `DispVal.value`, that will return the type you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to call `DispVal.data[2]` instead of `DispVal[2]`.  A `FieldValue` object has a bunch of things in it other than output values.  You want the actual `data`.